# Underscore.js Convert Object to upperCase Object

Tags: underscore.js

How can I convert a json object ["gen001", "abC0002"} to {"GEN001","ABC0002"] using
Underscore.j?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc9gh/

```
var func = function(greeting){ return greeting + ': ' + this.name };
func = _.bind(func, {name: 'moe'}, 'hi');
func();
```

Comment: Is that an array or an object?

Answer (score 1):

First, of all `{"gen001", "abC0002"}` is not a object.
If you need an object with keys `gen001` and `abC0002`, when you should also specify values:

```
var input = {"gen001":"some value", "abC0002":"some other value"};
```

In that case you can use [_.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) to loop through object properties and build another object with the keys you want:

```
var input = {"gen001":"some value", "abC0002":"some other value"},
    output = {};
_.each(
    input,
    function(element, index, list) {
        output[index.toUpperCase()] = element;
    }
);
console.log(output);
```

If you have an array:

```
var input = ["gen001", "abC0002"];
```

you can use [_.map](http://underscorejs.org/#map):

```
var input = ["gen001", "abC0002"];
var output = _.map(
    input,
    function(element) {
        return element.toUpperCase();
    }
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `_.map` uses `_.each`, so your second snippet works in both cases.

Comment: @psquared: But it does return an array even for objects.

Comment: @psquared: Second snippet works, but returns array of values from `input` object, not keys. That's why it cannot be used without additional modifications.

Comment: Ah, very good point.  I was fixated on the array-looking values in the question.